# Add state to history on specific search parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, history

I have a route `abc/xyz?i=foo&j=bar&k=stuff`. I have added `reloadOnSearch: false`. So the back button does not work. And that is what is intended

**BUT**

I do want to add a state to histor only when `$location.search().k` changes.

Comment: Normally, you just need to refresh the model. The view is a live representation of the model

Answer (score 2):

`$route.reload()` command is to reload the current view.
 `$location.path(give here new path)` to navigate to other views.

Comment: i works for me create a decorator to keep sync $urlRouter and $location

Comment: reloadOnSearch should not affect non-search param changes.

Comment: Then Try $route.reload(); or  $state.reload()  to reload the controller

Comment: It works, http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba8APIE3cKInwMFbuJPB?p=preview checkout console here